# is there a way to *ADD/UPDATE *filter on dashboard

Tags: apex, reporting

Looking at the example of using filters in the developer guide
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/analytics_api_dashboard_filter_results.htm 
to filter dashboard results i determined that we cannot add or update a

filter value on a dashboard using rest api,  we could only use the existing

filters that were on dashboard filter, i later confirmed it by sending a

request using workbench as well and i got the same response.

Is there a way to *ADD/UPDATE *filter on an
existing dashboard programatically using javascript/apex/api etc ?